# Splash screen on Expo Standalone App is not same with Expo Client App

Tags: expo

#### Configuration

I have an issue about splash configuration on Android in `app.json`.
It's fine if I run it on the Expo Client App but it's not after I build it as the standalone app.

I've tried as what is written on the [link](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/guides/splash-screens/).

Here is my configuration :

```
"expo": {
  ...
  "splash": {
     "backgroundColor": "#4286f4",
     "image": "./assets/images/splash/splash_full.png",
     "resizeMode": "contain",
     "tabletImage": "./assets/images/splash_full.png",
     "hideExponentText": true
  },
  ...
  "android": {
     "splash": {
        "backgroundColor": "#4286f4",
        "ldpi": "./assets/images/splash/splash_full.png",
        "mdpi": "./assets/images/splash/splash_full.png",
        "hdpi": "./assets/images/splash/splash_full.png",
        "xhdpi": "./assets/images/splash/splash_full.png",
        "xxhdpi": "./assets/images/splash/splash_full.png",
        "xxxhdpi": "./assets/images/splash/splash_full.png",
        "resizeMode": "contain",
        "hideExponentText": true
      },
  }
  ...
}
```

#### RESULT

`run` on Expo Client App :

[image: https://imgur.com/6Iw02vz]

`run` on Expo Standalone App :

[image: https://imgur.com/odQ5yD1]

#### EXPECTED

Expo Standalone App should be same with Expo Client App
How it's​ possible?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with splash resizeMode='cover' on Android.
Following the advice in https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/4494 I upgraded expo-cli and the problem is gone.

To summarize:

- Before SDK 33, expo-cli 2.x: worked well
- When upgraded to SDK 33, still using expo-cli 2.x, displayed a small splash surrounded by black background
- Upgraded expo-cli to 3.0.2, using sdk-33, works well